# Pseudo-finite field vs Nonstandard finite field

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, model-theory, peano-axioms

Let $\mathbb{N}^*$ be a countable non-standard model of [Peano arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) (PA) and let $\mathbb{Z}^*$ be the integers extended from $\mathbb{N}^*$. A [non-standard finite field](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/09/12/definable-subsets-over-nonstandard-finite-fields-and-almost-quantifier-elimination/) would be a ring $\mathbb{Z}^* /n^* \mathbb{Z}^*$ where $n^*$ is a non-standard prime number larger than any standard natural number.

How is a nonstandard finite field different from a [pseudo-finite field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-finite_field)? Can there be a mapping from one to the other?

Comment: Terence Tao's blog states "The ultraproduct $\mathbb{F}$ of finite fields is an important example of a pseudo-finite field". I am still interested in whether any countable pseudo-finite field can be mapped into any other countable pseudo-finite field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is negative. Not every pseudo-finite field, i.e a model of the theory of finite fields, is "nonstandard integers modulo a nonstandard prime". Every field of this form has characteristic zero. By contrast, there are pseudo-finite fields of positive characteristic:

http://www.logique.jussieu.fr/~zoe/papiers/Helsinki.pdf

(see page 17, example 5.1)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I know nothing about ring theory and less about fields. What would a countable pseudo-finite field of characteristic 0 look like? Would it have a cyclic order?

Comment: I don't really understand why a nonstandard finite field,  $\mathbb{Z}^* /n^* \mathbb{Z}^*$, would have characteristic $0$. Why doesn't it have characteristic $n^*$? There seems to be some implicit assumption we can tell when a prime is standard or nonstandard.

Comment: You are correct that viewed internally, from a model of ZFC which has nonstandard integers and does not know they are actually nonstandard, the characteristic of this ring is $n \ast$. But here we take an external view point and we know which integers are standard and which are not. There is a ring $\mathbb{Z} \ast$ which has nonstandard integers, and we quotient it by the ideal generated by an element $\n \ast$, which is larger than $1, 1+1, 1+1+1,...$ etc, but which is not divisible by any element other than itself and $1$. We get a field which is not of characteristic $p$ for any $p$...

Comment: ... so it has characteristic zero. There are no set theoretic or Godelian issues here.

Answer (score 0):

Quadratic residuosity gives an easy way to prove different pseudofinite fields non-isomorphic. e.g. $-1$ has a square root in the field if and only if $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$. More generally, you have a primitive $n$-th root of unity if and only if $p \equiv 1 \bmod n$.

My first instinct that you could prove that two such fields are (externally) isomorphic if and only if the two primes lie in the *same* equivalence class modulo every standard prime. The only if part is more likely than the if part, in my opinion.